# How do I Use a For Loop with GridBagLayout

Tags: java, eclipse, for-loop, gridbaglayout

I am wondering if there is any way in java to make a `for loop` place components onto a `JFrame` using `GridBagLayout`. I know, I could just use `GridLayout`, but I don't know how to make bigger buttons or components using a `for loop`. How would I use `GridBagLayout` and `for loop` to make different size buttons? Here is what I came up with, but it doesn't even print out multiple rows and doesn't work:

```
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        for(int j = 0; j <= 2; j++) {
            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            c.gridy = j;
            for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                c.gridx = i;
                panel.add(buttons.get(i), c);
            }

        }
```

I know, I did not add different size buttons, but I wanted to add that and also make this current program work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sample code doesn't work, but it has nothing to do with [`GridBagLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html). Let's take a closer look at your nested loops:

```
for(int j = 0; j <= 2; j++) {
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    c.gridy = j;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        c.gridx = i;
        panel.add(buttons.get(i), c); // <---- Do you see the problem?
    }
}
```

See my comment in your code. You presumably have an `ArrayList` with twelve buttons in it, and you want it arranged in three rows of four columns each, but according to you, your code "doesn't even print out multiple rows."

You've set your variable `i` to increment from 0 to 3, and on each iteration of the outer loop, it resets with the loop, going from 0 to 3 all over again. This means that you're adding the first four buttons from your `ArrayList` three times, instead of adding each of the twelve buttons once.

You can solve this problem by adding an index field which increments on each combined iteration of the outer and inner loops, like this:

```
int index = 0; // <---- Make sure you've declared and initialized the index

for(int j = 0; j <= 2; j++) {
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    c.gridy = j;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        c.gridx = i;
        panel.add(buttons.get(index), c); // <---- This will actually do what you want
        index++; // <---- Don't forget to increment the index to get to all the buttons
    }
}
```

As for the rest, you haven't specified how you want to alter the size of your buttons, but there are two ways:

**Preferred method:** experiment with the `gridwidth`, `gridheight` and `fill` fields of GridBagConstraints to change the buttons' sizes.

When you use `GridBagLayout`, imagine your container is divided into evenly sized boxes. `gridwidth` and `gridheight` tell a component how many of those boxes to use to display itself. `fill` tells a component how to expand to fill any extra space in its box if it's smaller than that box.

`GridBagLayout` doesn't give you the pixel perfect control that you might be expecting, but what it does give you is a neatly arranged and flexible layout.

**Non-preferred method:** use the `setPreferredSize()` method of the individual component to change its size. I mention this technique simply because it's possible, but I have to warn you now that while it's a technique, it's a bad technique.

When you use a layout manager, you want to let that manager control as much as possible given the parameters you've set for it. Users will do things that you might not have considered, like stretching the UI into odd proportions, having it fill their display, smashing it down to tiny sizes or whatever. Layout managers automatically adjust for changes, but when you give it rigid rules like "make this button exactly this many pixels wide," you can encounter undesirable results.

Comment: I know how to add different grid sizes but I dont know how to do it inside of a loop. How can I use a for loop if I only wanted 1 button to be bigger than the others?

Comment: @ElliotKing You understand that no one could answer your question because until now, you never indicated exactly what you wanted, right? Which button should be larger?

Comment: I just want to understand the concept. How would I make a button such as row 0 column 3 bigger (twice as big as the others) inside a `for loop?`

Comment: @ElliotKing Well... the point of doing stuff inside a loop is that you're looking for some regularity. Changing the size of just one button is irregular. You can still do it by using some branching logic. Use `JButton.getText()` to get the button's text. If it matches the text of the button that should be bigger, change the constraints accordingly. Inelegant, but effective.

Comment: the only problem I encounter is the button after it is covered up by the 2 times as wide button. For Example: If I wanted a twice as wide button, and it started at 0, 3, The 0,4 grid would be occupied by it as well. That would mean I would have to change the for-loop, since It would be placing a button at 0,4. Would making what some might call an "empty" button work that just occupies that space so the for loop could continue?

Comment: @ElliotKing Oh, right. You'd have to make room around it. You have to offset the buttons by however many extra boxes you're using. Instead of starting the next row at 0,4, start it at 0, 5. This is normal behavior. If you have a button that takes two spaces, you logically have to drop the next button two boxes over, not just one box, or you get overlap. At this point, you should really be re-thinking your layout and/or approach. I'd lay out one button on its own, maybe in its own container and layout and then do the rest via loop.

Comment: I will use gridbaglayout for some buttons with the for loops and empty areas then manually add on things using gridbaglayout and place it over the empty spaces.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to place components using [GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html) and a *for loop* and set different sizes, here is a working example:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setSize(500, 500);
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
c.weightx = 0.2;
c.weighty = 0.25;
for (int row = 1; row <= 3; row++) {
    c.gridy = row;
    for (int column = 1; column <= 4; column++) {
        c.gridx = column;
        c.ipadx = row * 2;
        c.ipady = row * column * 10;
        JButton button = new JButton("Button " + row + "," + column);
        panel.add(button, c);
    }
}
frame.add(panel);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

[image: GridBagLayout example]

More info on [how to use GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html).

Comment: But how would I use for loop is I wanted different sized buttons?